# Is it generally bad to await async operations in background processing (not needing the result)

Tags: c#, asynchronous-programming

So I've been working with background processing and event-driven systems, namely Azure WebJobs and ServiceBus. And while there is extensive use of `async/await` programming, I'm always wondering if it is generally bad practice to `await` asynchronous operations when not at all needing the results further in the program. More like a fire and forget.

I know that `await` won't block a thread but why even force the CPU to return to your method after the `await` if nothing happens or you don't need the method's result. Why wouldn't one just skip the `await` on your operation, the CPU never needs to return to your method and the thread can be returned to the pool. This situation is a fire-and-forget one.

EDIT: Code examples

```
async Task WriteEvent(string event)
{
    //some logic
    Event parsedEvent = new Event(event);
    //other logic

    _eventService.WriteEventAsync(parsedEvent); // no await
}
```

The alternative to the above code block:

```
async Task WriteEvent(string event)
{
    //some logic
    Event parsedEvent = new Event(event);
    //other logic

    await _eventService.WriteEventAsync(parsedEvent); // await
}
```

Comment: Giving a code short example (ideally taken from a real program, not an invented one) would probably make your question much interesting. I am curious if you have some production code with really no instruction after the `await`.

Comment: @DocBrown, I've added a contrived sample which mimics production code.

Comment: And the alternative? `await _eventService.WriteEventAsync(parsedEvent);` as the last line?

Comment: @DocBrown correct, question updated.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that some async libraries/frameworks are "lazy". These won't ever trigger the actual process unless you do a "get" or "eval". This might not be true with C# though.

Comment: Your first example is invalid, because you don't `await` anything nor return a `Task`. Did you mean `void WriteEvent`?

Comment: @Caleth, in C# `Task` is essentially `void` for `async/await` code which means your method doesn't return anything but it acts asynchronously, it enables `async/await` in your method.

Comment: Huh, I thought the compiler would complain about the lack. It should *warn* at least. My point is you don't have an asynchronous method in your first example

Comment: The compiler does warn about you not being able to get the result without `await`ing. Nonetheless, both methods are fully asynchronous but this is not the subject of the question. `await` purely says to the run-time, okay release the thread of the calling method (and don't remember its context, which is another discussion) but come back to the calling method when the delegate event is raised (i.e. when the `WriteEventAsync` returns from work).

Comment: Addition to the above. The run-time will remember the calling context without explicit instruction not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with fire-and-forget asynchronous operation. But you need to make sure you can handle possible exceptions, as there is no one to handle them in such situation.

One possible solution is :

```
async void WriteEventAsyncEx()
{
    try
    {
        await _eventService.WriteEventAsync(parsedEvent);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception
        // letting it through would result in UnhandledTaskException killing application
    }
}

async Task WriteEvent(string event)
{
    //some logic
    Event parsedEvent = new Event(event);
    //other logic

    WriteEventAsyncEx(); // no await
}
```

Comment: If anything, add a callback to be called on failure.  This way you can safely ignore the called task until something has gone wrong.

Comment: @Neil, could you maybe provide more context?

Comment: @ethane I meant, launch the task asynchronously but passing a method that gets called in case of failure, in order to remediate the issue of "not being able to handle possible exceptions".

Comment: @Neil What's the difference then? You basically have a callback that is called every time, why change it to a callback for errors only?

Comment: @Neil, wouldn't this need the call to be `await`ed anyway? The other question is then: is there an advantage of a callback over just `try...catch`?

Comment: @ethane No, you could call it asynchronously.  That's the point of a callback is to do something when the job is done.  Otherwise for a synchronous call, the same thing can be accomplished by making the next line do the work of the callback.  To your other question, a `try.. catch` assumes the call is *synchronous*.   In other words you can't catch errors which will occur later in an asynch call without using a callback.

Comment: @Neil, I understand that in terms of a run-time like node.js and even ajax requests, but in other languages like C#? Even though `Func`s are first-order data types, an example of this might help the cause. I imagine restructuring the `_eventService` for method-chaining.

Comment: @ethane Ok, so don't use callbacks.  You still have a problem where you cannot deal with exceptions.  Just offering a possible solution to this problem.  You're welcome to deal with it in other ways as well.